# CSS media queries doesn't work on any browser

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I looked on every thread and I tried every possible solution to no avail. It just doesn't work on any browser...

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="bg">
    </div>
    
</body>
```

CSS:

```
    @media only screen and (max-width: 1200){
    .bg{
        background-color: green;
    }
}

*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.bg{
    background-color: black;
    height: 100vh;   
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 problems that are preventing it from working:

1. You need to **specify the unit** (e.g. px) in the `(max-width: 1200px)` - otherwise it doesn't recognise the breakpoint
2. You need to **include the media query *after* the default css** for `.bg`. Because you are including the media query *before* `.bg{background-color: black;...}`, this is overriding the CSS rule in the media query that set is to green.

See this in a working snippet (Click "Expand Snippet" to see it in fullscreen with a black background):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.bg {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100vh;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .bg {
    background-color: green;
  }
}
```

```html
  <div class="bg">
  </div>
```

Comment: Very nice observation @FluffyKitten

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `min-width` in your media queries and apply them using mobile first approach. It means first you apply default styles which will apply to any screen if there are no media queries. Then you reset styles for larger screen sizes. The default styles then only apply to smaller screens.

Example:

```css
/* Default style */
.sample-class {
  color: #ff0000;
}

/* Reset style for screen sizes that are 768px or higher */
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .sample-class {
    color: #777777;
  }
}
```

Do make sure that you are implementing styles in the order above.

Comment: So, I need to put the classes/ids styles before the media query?

Comment: CSS is applied from top to bottom, and on the basis of selector specificity. To read about specificity see this article: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp
If you are using same selector and applying different styles (let's say color), the color which was applied second will take precedence. Same thing applies with media queries. First you set default styles. Later when you want to change those styles for certain breakpoints. You add styles below the default styles so that they override the initially applied styles. Also read about CSS mobile first approach.

Comment: https://zellwk.com/blog/how-to-write-mobile-first-css/

Comment: Now it makes sense, Thanks!